# How to find first nontrivial fibration in Whitehead tower of the $n$-sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles, fibration

Consider the Whitehead tower of the $n$-sphere $X = S^n$:
$$... \rightarrow X' \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} X,$$
where $X'$ is $n$-connected.  **Explicitly, what is $X'$ and what is the fibration $p$?**  How do I compute them?

Thoughts: Intuitively, I am looking for the first nontrivial "delooping" of the $n$-sphere.  For example, for $n=1$, I know that $X' = \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is the universal covering of $S^1$.  However for $n \geq 2$, I have no idea how to compute $X'$ or $p$.  Perhaps in the case $n=2$, $p$ is the Hopf fibration.

Comment: Yes, it's the Hopf fibration for $n = 2$; in general I think it's not a manifold. It's the homotopy fiber of the map $S^n \to B^n \mathbb{Z}$ coming from any generator of $H^n(S^n, \mathbb{Z})$; I don't know if it has a meaningfully simpler description than that in general.